# sequence item 1: expected string, OrderedDict found

Tags: python, django, api, ordereddict

I'm trying to perform a check, but I get an error `sequence item 1: expected string, OrderedDict found`. With what it can be connected? This is the function in the documentation.

https://github.com/cloudipsp/python-sdk/blob/master/cloudipsp/helpers.py#L85

```
def get_transaction(self, request, signature, origin):
    print(type(origin))  #dict

    data = origin.copy()
    result = None
    trans = None
    if data:
        data['signature'] = signature
        data = dict((k, v) for k, v in data.iteritems() if v not in (None, ''))
        data = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items()))

        if helper.is_valid(data, self.secret_key, self.api.api_protocol):  #sequence item 1: expected string, OrderedDict found
```

**Traceback**

```
File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/midgard/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/midgard/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/midgard/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/midgard/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/midgard/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/midgard/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/midgard/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py" in inner
  40.             return func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/work_projects/startapp/midgard/payments/views.py" in result
  319.     data, trans, _res = integration.get_transaction(request, signature, origin)

File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/work_projects/startapp/midgard/fondy/integration.py" in get_transaction
  110.                 str_sign = sep.join([self.secret_key, data])

Exception Value: sequence item 1: expected string, OrderedDict found
```

Comment: It looks like `data` has to be a string. Read `is_valid` and **also** `get_signature`, which is raising error

Comment: `str_sign = sep.join([secret_key, params])` error in `params` at `get_signature`. `params` must be a `string`..

Comment: could you post the full traceback of the error?

Comment: But `params` is a dictionary, judging by the code ...

Comment: @olinox14 added traceback

Comment: Trying to guess.  `self.api.api_protocol` is `2.0` right? try to change it.

Comment: `protocol 2.0` expects `params` to be a string. while other protocols expect `params` to be a `dict`. you are using the wrong protocol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm encoded data to `base64` and rewrote `is_valid`

```
def get_transaction(self, request, signature, origin):
    data = origin.copy()
    result = None
    trans = None
    if data:
        data['signature'] = signature
        data = dict((k, v) for k, v in data.iteritems() if v not in (None, ''))
        data = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items()))

        if 'signature' in data:
            result_signature = data['signature']
            del data['signature']
        else:
            raise ValueError('Incorrect data')
        if 'response_signature_string' in data:
            del data['response_signature_string']

        from hashlib import sha1
        from cloudipsp.configuration import __sign_sep__ as sep

        if self.api.api_protocol == '2.0':
            import pickle
            data = pickle.dumps(origin).encode('base64', 'strict')
            str_sign = sep.join([self.secret_key, data])

            calc_sign = sha1(str_sign.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        else:
            data = [secret_key]
            data.extend([str(params[key]) for key in sorted(iter(params.keys()))
                         if params[key] != '' and not params[key] is None])
        signature = sha1(sep.join(data).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

        if result_signature == calc_sign:
```

Comment: can't simply pass a fake protocol to `is_valid` ? like `if helper.is_valid(data, self.secret_key, "1.0")`?

Comment: @LanteDellarovere But I need protocol 2.0